# Are Windows TideSDK apps running in sandbox?

Tags: tidesdk

The windows software I create in TideSDK, does it run in sandbox or can I have full access to file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and no..

If you are loading the page which is from local hdd / filesystem you will have full access to the filesystem through window.Ti object. you can see the documentation of various apis available [here](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/)

Secondly if you are loading any remote server url .. you will not have access to any of extended apis as the "window.Ti" object is not available.